# PRISM Sharing styles between modules

Tags: silverlight, prism

I'm testing the reference project that karl has made for silverlight.
In it on of the modules have a StaticResource binding to a resource that is in the App.xaml file.

When i do the same the design view does not show the style in my module.
What am i missing?

- Common contains Styles.xaml
- Shell merges Styles.xaml
- ModuleA {StaticResource StyleA}

Comment: What do you mean by "the reference project that karl has made"? Link please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of the design tool. I suppose that the assembly of ModuleA is not referenced by the Shell, right? Then the tool has no reason to know that ModuleA will be loaded only when the Shell is loaded. I doesn't know that these projects are related, hence it doesn't look for styles in the Shell project when it loads a view from ModuleA in the designer.

One solution would be to reference the shared styles dictionary in every view of ModuleA that you want to open in the designer, but this is not a very good solution as it is a code duplication. Another solution, if you are using Expression Blend, might be to use [design-time dictionaries](http://adamkinney.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/design-time-resources-in-expression-blend-4-rc/), but I don't know if there is something like this for Visual Studio designer.

Comment: You're absolutly right about what you're writing... The thing is.. it works for Karl in his reference project :)
But i'll look in to design-time dictionaries think i saw it somewhere.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as accepted since it doesnt seem possible to do what i want :) Thanks for design-time dictionaries going to look into them a little more as soon as i get blend

Comment: Yeah, how does StockTraderRI reference project do this without a reference to Shell?

Answer (score 0):

I can across the same problem.  I've seen some Prism applications a "Common" project to define things like "Region Names" constants and etc.  If the all the styles were defined there that might be a better solution.   That way each module could reference these styles or create thier module specific styes.